# Call to a member function get() on a non-object in Controller

Tags: get, zend-framework2

I have defined one variable in local.php and want to access it in my controller file in ZF2,

Controller-

```
namespace Common\Project;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class DimestoreCheck extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function isDimestoreHost()
        {
            $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('log_configuration');
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($config); exit; 
        }
    }
```

when I am trying to print `$config` variable it is giving me below error,

> b>Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   **/var/www/vm/sct-rcs-services/module/Rcs/src/Common/Project/DimestoreCheck.php**
>   on line **14**

Please suggest how can I resolve this error.

Comment: I am trying to call $this->getServiceLocator()->get('log_configuration'); "I get Call to a member function get() on a non-object". It seems like my getServiceLocator is empty.

Comment: Is your method `isDimestoreHost` an action of the controller? To verify if the service manager was actually set, try to put a `var_dump` in the `setServiceLocator` of the `AbstractController` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the array config first :

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

Then you will be able to access your custom key :

```
$myConfig = $config['log_configuration'];
```